# with php fopen() flock() file() Why does it work like this

Tags: php, file, fopen, flock

so 
if i fopen one file with a+ like

```
fopen($filepath,'a+');
file($filepath);
```

and then  i use file($filepath) get the file contents it's ok

but why i when 
i locked the file with flock i also can use file() function get the content
why ?

```
$fp = fopen($filepath, "a+");
while (1) {
  $f =flock($fp,LOCK_EX);
  if($f){
    fwrite($fp,'abc');
    echo "ok loked \n";
    sleep(1);
    $te =file($filepath);
    if(strlen($te[0])==10){
      echo "this is cont ".$te[0]."\n";
      echo "ok this the end \n";
      ftruncate($fp,0);
      fflush($fp);  
    }
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    break;
  }
} 
fclose($fp);
```

1. what about they relation?
2. when flock file the file()function is use the fopen resource？
3. file is independent function or use  fopen？

Comment: Sidenote: If this isn't pseudo-code, you have a syntax error in `echo "ok loked "\n";`. It's throwing off syntax highlighting.

Comment: Sorry, but I find that rather hard to believe `echo "ok loked "\n";` will throw a parse error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, you've made an edit `echo "ok loked \n";`

Comment: Yup so about the flock function?

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` and `file` are two different functions.

> **fopen** The fopen function does something entirely different—it opens a file
> descriptor, which functions as a stream to read or write the file. It
> is a much lower-level function, a simple wrapper around the C fopen
> function, and simply calling fopen won't do anything but open a
> stream.
>
> **file** — Reads entire file into an array

Comment: how about the    flock() when i use ,what happend ? its  locked the file ? but i can use file() get content   
@being-sunny

Comment: see php `flock` warning section http://php.chinaunix.net/manual/hu/function.flock.php

Answer (score 0):

flock is *per process*. So if the same process (including all threads) attempts flock multiple times it will always succeed.

Read the warnings at the end of the documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php